# Windows TCP redirection

Tags: windows, networking, nat, tcp, redirection

On my Windows PC (192.168.1.123) , I have an application that connects to 1.2.3.4 on port 3333 by default, I would like to redirect the traffic to 127.0.0.1 port 2222.

Under Linux, this can be accomplished by entering this on my PC.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.123 -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 3333 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2222
```

Is there a way to do the above on Windows?

Comment: What version of windows are you running? I'm not sure this is possible without additional software on windows (if at all).

Comment: on linux this is possible with `nc` like `nc -l 1234 | nc 1.2.3.4 5678` and you can get nc on windows with cygwin and possibly with gow. Another way in windows is with the netsh  command , something like `netsh add v4tov4 listenport..........`  . you can google that netsh command.

Answer (score 0):

on linux this is possible with `nc` like `nc -l 1234 | nc 1.2.3.4 5678` and you can get nc on windows with cygwin

An alternative to nc is in windows with the netsh  command

it's mentioned here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4422 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.33`

Comment: Ive read somewhere that the netsh solution only works if you're receiving then forwarding traffic. Did I interpret it wrong by any chance? I'll try the nc command in abit.